# I'm unable to open a terminal in vsCode. Error message "The terminal process terminated with exit code: 3221225477". What should I do?

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

I'm not sure why but I can't open a terminal in vscode. I'm running windows 10, and my version of vscode is 1.46. The error code is as follows

> The terminal process terminated with exit code: 3221225477

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this github issue.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95111

It looks like the antivirus program could trigger this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is just for corner case.

Having same issue after deleting ~/.bash_profile on Windows 10. Working correctly after restore it.

```bash
# generated by Git for Windows
test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
```